# How to stop repeating lines in a while loop

Tags: python

my code:

```
def login():
    print("Welcome to David's and John's Tenant Management System!")
    print("(1)Admin (2)Customer (3)Exit")
    while True:
        if selection() == "1":
            print("f")  # admin login
        if selection() == "2":
            print("Are you an existing user? Enter 1 if YES, 2 for NO.")
            break
login()
```

output:

```
Welcome to David's and John's Tenant Management System!
(1)Admin (2)Customer (3)Exit
Please enter a number: 2
Please enter a number: 2
```

it keeps on repeating "Please enter a number" twice, instead of once. Sorry if I'm asking a dumb question.

Comment: Because you're calling `selection()` twice…?!

Comment: `selected_value = selection()` and then do `if selected_value == "1":` and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't show your function `selection()` but looks like you can fix your code next way:

```
while True:
    selected = selection()
    if selected == "1":
        print("f")  # admin login
    elif selected == "2":
        print("Are you an existing user? Enter 1 if YES, 2 for NO.")
        break
```